# Java File Parsing - Go word by word

Tags: java, file, string-parsing

I have a file content as Follows:

Sample.txt:
Hi my name is john 
and I am an engineer. How are you

The output I want is an arrayList of string like [Hi,my,name,is,john,and,I,am,an,engineer,.,How,are,you]

The standard java function parses it as line and I would get an array containing the lines. I am confused as to which approach I should use to get the following output.

Any help is appretiated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are getting the strings as whole lines, but just want the words, you could use `.split(" ")` on the words, as this would return an array containing individual words with no spaces. If you want to do this within the file reading, you could use something like the following...

```
public ArrayList<String> readWords(File file) throws IOException {
  ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
  String cLine = "";
  BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
  while ((cLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    for (String word : cLine.split(" ")) {words.add(word);}
  }
  reader.close();
  return words;
}
```

which would return an `ArrayList<String>` containing all of the individual words in the file.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, @JHNUXER for the help. How do I include "."(Full stop) in to the array

Comment: @paramtrivedi oh yeah, I must have missed that in your question when I answered, sorry. If you're still interested, you'd probably want to use regex to separate out dots. Alternatively, you could use `endsWith` to check if a word ends with a full stop, and if it does, strip that off with `substring` and add a full stop to the list.

Answer (score 2):

`.nextLine()` will get one whole line but `.next()` will go word by word

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Mitchel0022

Answer (score 1):

You could check out using the `Scanner` class with the `.next()` method.

Answer (score 1):

This will read the file and collect all words into a list of strings.

**Edit**: Updated so as to handle punctuation and the likes as distinct words:

```
    try {
        List<String> words = Files.lines(Paths.get("/path/to/sample.txt"))
            .map(line -> line.split("\\b"))
            .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
            .filter(w -> !w.trim().isEmpty())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

        return words;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // handle error 
    }
```